# Eclipse plugin - issue passing empty command arguments from option preference in plugin.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, plugin.xml

I need to send empty command argument from an option preference implemented in `plugin.xml` when building the eclipse project.

My approach is the addition of `commandGenerator` option attribute, very similar implementation as `applicabilityCalculator` I implemented before and working fine, where you intercept the implementation of the argument in `plugin.xml` and add your own java code to play around with it, the attribute `commandGenerator` supposed to override the option commands in case you need to override them. The problem is that after implementing the functionality it doesn’t react as expected, actually it doesn’t even care about it and it doesn’t take into account its implementation, it ignores it, so the question is:

Why is `commandGenerator` attribute in plugin.xml ignored therefore not executing its java class implementation? Am I missing something else or mixing up some order of execution?

```
    <tool
        id="ilg.gnumcueclipse.managedbuild.cross.riscv.tool.base"
        isAbstract="true"
        name="RISC-V Targets common options">
        <option
            defaultValue=""
            commandGenerator="ilg.gnumcueclipse.managedbuild.cross.riscv.validation.OptionCommandGenerator"
            id="ilg.gnumcueclipse.managedbuild.cross.riscv.option.base.target.validate"
            isAbstract="false"
            name=""
            tip="Architecture-ABI Validation message"
            valueType="string"
            applicabilityCalculator="ilg.gnumcueclipse.managedbuild.cross.riscv.validation.ValidationMsg">
        </option>
```

If option is disabled from preferences then it takes the `defaultValue=""` which is empty and that is perfect, it builds with no errors, but if the option is enabled --> I do apply and close --> and build project then fails as it takes the value form the option and passes that value to the command arguments, which is not supported, so my guess is that I need to pass an empty argument.

I tried to `validationMessage.setCommand("");` , `validationMessage.setCommandFalse("");` , `validationMessage.setValue("");` and `validationMessage.setDefaultValue("");` from the IOption variable and still sending the value of the IOption variable to the command line arguments when building the project, therefore failing when building project.

Any idea of what the issue could be and how could it be resolved? Thanks.
Please feel free to ask if extra information is needed to find the issue.
(jus to mention `OptionCommandGenerator.java` Path is fine)

Comment: What extension point is this? As the question stands I have no idea what you are asking about.

Comment: extension-point: id="toolchains", schema="schema/toolchains.exsd", extension point="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.buildDefinitions"

Comment: Hi @greg-449, I just rephrased the question to see if it makes more sense now: Why is commandGenerator attribute in plugin.xml ignored therefore not executing its java class implementation? Am I missing something else or mixing up some order of execution?

Comment: Since this is an Eclipse CDT extension point I can't answer as I don't anything about CDT.